# How to get a reference of cucumber RuntimeOptions when using cucumber-java and junit?

Tags: java, groovy, junit, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I am using cucumber-java in groovy code. I prefer cucumber-java to cucumber-groovy because I can run the tests like plain old good JUnit tests. However, the step definition templates spitted out by cucumber are in java style. Instead, I would like to have a groovy style. For example, in java style, you will get something like

```
@When("^an HTTP GET request is sent to obtain config.xml of \"([^\"]*)\"$")
public void an_HTTP_GET_request_is_sent_to_obtain_config_xml_of(String arg1) throws Throwable {
    // Express the Regexp above with the code you wish you had
    throw new PendingException();
}
```

Since I am using groovy, I would like to get something like

```
@When(/^an HTTP GET request is sent to obtain config.xml of "([^"]*)"$/)
void 'an HTTP GET request is sent to obtain config.xml of'(String arg1) {
    // Express the Regexp above with the code you wish you had
    throw new PendingException();
}
```

I am thinking to implement such a feature. Basically, my idea is to add a new field, maybe called `templateLanguage`, in `cucumber.api.CucumberOptions`. When this new field is equal to `groovy`, then the groovy-style templates will be spitted. This will probably involve an if statement in `cucumber.runtime.java.JavaSnippet.template()`, such as
`if( runtimeOptions.getTemplateLanguage().toLowerCase().equals('groovy') ) {...}`
However, my question is: how can I get a reference of the runtimeOptions that is passed in like

```
@CucumberOptions(
        format = ["pretty", "html:build/cucumber"],
        features="src/test/resources/cucumber_features/api/job_view.feature",
        glue=['com.yahoo.adcd.jenkins.tests.smoke.api.cucumber.job.view'],
        strict = true
)
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Did you check `RuntimeOptions.java` at  https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/core/src/main/java/cucumber/runtime/RuntimeOptions.java

Comment: Yes, I did. But didn't find anything that would help? Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you managed to get a resolution for this?

Comment: If you want to add a feature to Cucumber-groovy, maybe you should have a look at the project on Github: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm-groovy. For questions on how to implement this, it's probably best to contact the developers on Slack: https://cucumber.io/support#slack

Answer (score 0):

In a case like this, you would need to write your own boot class since there is no dependency injection for `RuntimeOptions`. A good starting location is to look at `cucumber.api.cli.Main`. You would need to create your own class that extends `RuntimeOptions`, then add in your logic there.

This solution, however, will not allow you run the app using the `CucumberOptions` annotation anymore. If you do prefer using the annotation though, you would need to also implement your own custom annotation and override the `RuntimeOptionsFactory` to use your annotation, and then use that factory in your new main class to create the runtime dynamically.